# Selenium IDE - Click command keeps loading and wont go to the next step

Tags: selenium

I want to click this button:

```
html:
onclick="javascript:return  scForm.postEvent(this,event,'contentlink:externallink(id=FIELD8547822616)')"  class="scContentButton" href="#">Insert External Link
```

After clicking the button, a new window will be opened.

I've tried several command such as click, fire event - click. Both  of them will open the new window but it won't go to the next step. The "click" row will be highlighted yellow (means that it's still in progress).

Why is it after click, the next step isn't executed ?

My Code:
Hi here's my code in selenium ide

```
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//div[@id='EditorPanel']/div[3]/div/table[5]/tbody/tr/td/table[4]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/a[3]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectWindow</td>
    <td>Sitecore</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=Url</td>
    <td>http://bookofbetterways.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=OK</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>selectWindow</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add to your code the following command before the command selectWindow, so the script will wait, the window to be loaded before select it.

```
<tr>
    <td>waitForPopUp</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on assumption that your next step is to be executed on the opened window there may be a case that after clicking when the new window is opened you are not selecting the opened window.

Comment: my next step after click the button is selectWindow. But it's not executed. It keeps running on the click step/

Comment: Could you please paste your code here so that things could be more clear.